# Get boundingRect output from QPainter.drawText in pyside6

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I'm working with Qt6 in Python via the PySide6 binding. According to [the Qt6 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#drawText-4), the `QPainter.drawText` method can output a `boundingRect` parameter that bounds the text drawn:

> `void QPainter::drawText(const QRect &rectangle, int flags, const QString &text, QRect *boundingRect = nullptr)`
>
> ...
>
> The boundingRect (if not null) is set to the what the bounding rectangle should be in order to enclose the whole text. For example, in the following image, the dotted line represents boundingRect as calculated by the function, and the dashed line represents rectangle:

The [PySide docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtGui/QPainter.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText) have the same text and the same code example, except translated (presumably automatically) into Python. However, the signature of the Python method does not include the `boundingRect` output parameter (and such output parameters aren't really good Python style anyway).

Trying to call the Python `drawText` method with a `boundingRect` parameter fails on too-many-arguments, and the in-module docs don't mention it. Thus I assume this is an error in the Web docs due to copying over the C++ API version. `drawText` always returns None. Is there any way to get the `boundingRect` output from `drawText` in PySide?

Comment: It seems a bug (or missing feature) in PySide, since PyQt always returns a QRect/QRectF when using a `drawText()` overload that has a rectangle as its argument. This is quite common in PyQt: every time a C++ function argument uses a pointer that will be likely modified by the function itself, the argument is normally absent, and will instead be the return value of the function. I suggest you to file a bug at https://bugreports.qt.io with the PYSIDE tag.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like that function is actually returning a QRect, which appears superficially to be the one I want. It's just the documentation that shows it returning None.

Comment: You're right, even the `help()` in the python interactive shell doesn't show it. I then suggest you to file a report about that anyway, so that they can fix the documentation.

Comment: @TomHunt Please consider posting an answer to your own question, This will help people with a similar problem finding your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the documentation, there is no `boundingRect` output parameter in the PySide API (as expected from the conventions of Python APIs). Instead, the `drawText` method simply returns a `QRect` which is the same as returned in the `boundingRect` parameter in C++. This is documented neither in the Web documentation, nor in the `help()` output for the class.

A [bug has been filed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2411) with Qt regarding the documentation issue.